# trouble installing an archived package in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I want to install the "ReadImages" package in R. This package was archived, so I had downloaded the tar.gz file. I had tried almost all the steps mentioned to install a package from a source file. But all my attempts are in vain. Need help

I had tried the below methods

```
> library(devtools)
> setwd("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\packages")
> install("ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz")
Error: ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz is not a directory


> setwd("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\packages\\ReadImages_0.1.3.3\\ReadImages\\R")
> for (i in list.files()){source(i)}
> library(ReadImages)
Error in library(ReadImages) : there is no package called ‘ReadImages’


> install.packages("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\packages\\ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL) 
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'ReadImages' ...
** package 'ReadImages' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ReadImages'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/ReadImages'
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/i386/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "C:/Users/Downloads/packages/ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\packages\\ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Downloads/packages/ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install the [tools to build from source](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) first?

Comment: No, I thought the above commands suffice. I am going to install the Rtools215.exe, meanwhile can u give me the steps that I should follow to install from a tar.gz file. I seem to be missing something out there

Comment: The last command is correct -- it would work if you had the tools installed, but since you didn't, it didn't.

Comment: perhaps specifying your library location without adjusting working directory... `install.packages("ReadImages")` ... `library(""ReadImages" , lib.loc = "insert_library_location_here")`